# Can I orphan an existing branch?

Tags: git, github, branch

I've created a few branches in a repo, and realized too late (after making various changes to them) that I should have made them orphans.  Is it possible to orphan them after the fact?

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure it's possible. There might be a more efficient way, but this seems like it would work:

1. Find the first commit in your old branch, and call it `FIRST`.
2. `git checkout --orphan new-branch $FIRST`
3. `git checkout old-branch`
4. `git rebase --onto new-branch $FIRST`

Now you have the original branch at `old-branch` and a new, orphaned branch at `new-branch`. You can, if you like, either delete or rename `old-branch`, and rename `new-branch` to `old-branch`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow #1. How do I assign a commit to a variable?  Or is that pseudocode, and I should just replace $FIRST with the SHA1 hash or some other means of addressing the commit?

Comment: @iconoclast yes, that's what I mean :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I need to commit after line #2.  Line #4 fails with `fatal: Needed a single revision
Does not point to a valid commit: data-model` without it.  I'm not sure what difference the `rebase` makes in this case: is it really necessary?

Comment: The rebase brings the rest of the commits onto the branch, after the first. And yes, you're right, there should be a commit after step 2.

Comment: if there "should be a commit after step 2", could you update your answer to reflect this? it's not really clear until trying, failing, and reading the comments :]