# How to make existing branch an orphan in git

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

Is there a way to make an *existing branch* an orphan in git?

`git checkout --orphan` seems to only *create* a new orphan?

Comment: You will be able to cherry-pick right after creating the orphan branch (git 2.9.x/2.10, Q3 2016). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38285663/6309).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I orphan an existing branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21843130/can-i-orphan-an-existing-branch) (possible duplicate found after 4.5 years !). The answer there works really well.

Answer (score 16):

You are correct that `git checkout --orphan` creates only new orphan branches.  The trick is that this process leaves the index undisturbed.  Thus, [Nick Volynkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284471/1256452) will work, as long as your Git is not too ancient.

If you want to keep the original commit message, you can replace his:

```sh
$ git commit -m'first commit in orphan'
```

with:

```
$ git commit -C master~2
```

If your Git is sufficiently old that you do not have `git checkout --orphan`, this should also do it:

```sh
$ commit=<hash>  # or, e.g., commit=$(git rev-parse master~2)
$ git branch newbranch $( \
    git log --no-walk --pretty=format:%B $commit | \
    git commit-tree -F - "${commit}^{tree}" \
)
$ git checkout newbranch
$ git cherry-pick $commit..master # may want -x; see below
```

where you choose the starting-point from `git log` or using the `~` syntax with an existing branch name (this continues to use `master~2` as in Nick's answer).

If all you wanted was a recipe, that should do the trick, but if you want to know what's going on and why this works (and when it doesn't), read on. :-)

## Things you need to know about branches

Before we go any further seems like a good idea to define some items and describe what's going on.

#### Branch names vs the commit graph

First, let's make a clear distinction between a branch *name*, like `master` or `newbr`, and various portions of the *commit graph*.  A branch name simply points to one commit, designated a *tip commit* or *branch tip*, within the graph:

```
*--o--o---o--o    <-- master
    \    /
     o--o--o--o   <-- brA
            \
             o    <-- brB
```

This graph has three branch tips, pointed-to by `master`, `brA`, and `brB`.  The ancestry of the tip of `brB`, for instance, goes back in a wiggly line, always moving leftward and sometimes up too, to the (single) root commit `*` (as distinguished from all the other non-root `o` commits).  The fact that commit `*` has no commits to its left—no parent commit to point-to—is what makes it a root commit.

This root commit is on all the branches.  Other commits are on multiple branches as well.  There's a merge commit on `master`, which brings commits from `brA` in, even though `brA` then has two commits that `master` does not, for instance.  To follow `master` back to the root, you must go straight left, and *also* down-and-left at the merge, and then back up-and-left where `brA` splits off.

Note that we can have multiple branch names pointing to a single commit, or branch names that point to "tip" commits that are embedded within another branch:

```
*--o--o---o--o    <-- master
    \    /
     o--o--o      <-- brA
            \
             o    <-- brB, brC
```

Here we've "rewound" branch `brA` by one commit, so that the right-side middle-row commit is the tip of `brA`, even though it's one commit back from the tip of `brB`.  We've added a new branch, `brC`, that points to the *same* commit as `brB` (making it a tip twice, as it were; let's hope this commit is not a tip in the British-English "rubbish tip" sense of the word: "ugh, this commit is an absolute *tip!*").

#### The DAG

The graph has a series of nodes `o`, each of which point to some parent(s) that are generally on their left.  The lines (or arrows, really) connecting the nodes are directed edges: one-way streets or rail-lines, if you will, connecting child nodes in the graph back to their parents.

The nodes, plus the directed edge links from child to parent, form the *commit graph*.  Because this graph is directed (child to parent) and acyclic (once you depart a node, you can never come back to it), this is called a **D**irected **A**cyclic **G**raph or DAG.  DAGs have all kinds of nice theoretical properties, most of which we can ignore for this SO answer.

#### DAGs may have *disconnected subgraphs*

Now let's consider this alternative graph:

```
*--o--o---o--o   <-- master
    \    /
     o--o--o     <-- brA

*--o--o--o       <-- orph
```

This new branch, whose tip is named `orph`, has its own root and is completely disconnected from the other two branches.

Note that multiple roots are a necessary precondition for having (non-empty) disjoint sub-graphs, but depending on how you want to view these graphs, they may not be sufficient.  If we were to *merge* (the tip commit of) `brA` into `orph`<sup>1</sup> we would get this:

```
*--o--o---o--o   <-- master
    \    /
     o--o--o     <-- brA
            \
*--o--o--o---o   <-- orph
```

and the two "graphs fragments" are now joined.  However, there exist sub-graphs (such as those starting from `orph^1` and `brA`, the two parents of `orph`) that are disjoint.  (This is not particularly relevant to creating orphan branches, it's just something you should understand about them.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Modern Git rejects a casual attempt to do such a merge, since the two branches have no merge base.  Older versions of Git do the merge, not necessarily with sensible results.

---

#### `git checkout --orphan`

The `orph` branch is the kind of branch that `git checkout --orphan` makes: a branch that will have a new, disconnected root.

The way it *gets* there is to make a branch *name* that points to no commit at all.  Git calls this an "unborn branch", and branches in this state have only a sort of half-existence, because Git leaks the implementation through.

#### Unborn branches

A branch name, by definition, always points to the tip-most commit on that branch.  But this leaves Git with a problem, especially in a totally fresh new repository that has no commits at all: where can `master` point?

The fact is that an unborn branch can't point anywhere, and because Git implements branch names by recording them as a <name, commit-ID> pair,<sup>2</sup> it simply cannot record the branch until there is a commit.  Git's solution to this dilemma is to cheat: the branch name does not go into the branch records at all, but instead, only into the `HEAD` record.

The `HEAD`, in Git, records the current branch name.  For "detached HEAD" mode, `HEAD` records the actual commit ID—and in fact, this is how Git determines whether a repository / work-tree is in "detached HEAD" mode: if its `HEAD` file contains a branch *name*, it is not detached, and if it contains a commit ID, it is detached.  (No other states are permitted.)

Hence, to create an "orphan branch", or during that awkward period when there is no commit yet for `master`, Git stores the name in `HEAD`, but does not actually create the branch name yet.  (That is, there is no entry in `.git/refs/heads/` for it, and no line in `.git/packed-refs` for it.)

As a peculiar side effect, this means that you can only have one unborn branch.  The unborn branch's name is stored in `HEAD`.  Checking out another branch, with or without `--orphan`, or any commit by ID—any action that updates `HEAD`—wipes out all traces of the unborn branch.  (A new `git checkout --orphan`, of course, replaces it with the trace of the new unborn branch.)

Once you make a first commit, the new branch springs into being, because...

---

<sup>2</sup>With "unpacked" references, the name is just a path in the file system: `.git/refs/heads/master`.  The commit-ID is then simply the contents of this file.  Packed references are stored differently, and Git is evolving other ways to handle the name-to-ID mapping, but this is the most basic and it's currently still needed to allow Git to work.

There are two obvious ways to keep unborn branches around, but Git uses neither of them.  (For the record, these are: create an empty file, or use the special "null hash".  The empty file trick has an obvious flaw: it will be very fragile in the face of command or computer crashes, much more so than using the null hash.)

---

#### The commit process

In general, the process of making a *new* commit, in Git, goes like this:

1. Update and/or populate the index, also called the staging area or cache: `git add` various files.  This step creates Git's *blob* objects, which store the actual file contents.
2. Write the index into one or more *tree* objects (`git write-tree`).  This step creates, or in a few rare cases reuses, at least one (top level) tree.  That tree has entries for each file and sub-directory; for files, it lists the blob-ID, and for sub-directories, it lists (after creating) the tree that contains the sub-directory's files and trees.  Note, incidentally, that this leaves the index undisturbed, ready for the *next* commit.
3. Write a commit object (`git commit-tree`).  This step needs a bunch of items.  For our purposes the main interesting ones are the (single) tree object that goes with this commit—that's the one we just got from step 2—and a list of parent commit IDs.
4. Write the new commit's ID into the current branch name.

Step 4 is *how and why* branch names always point to the tip commit.  The `git commit` command gets the branch name from `HEAD`.  It also, during step 3, gets the primary (or *first*, and usually only) parent commit ID the same way: it reads `HEAD` to get the branch name, then reads the tip commit ID from the branch.  (For merge commits, it reads the additional parent IDs—usually just one—from `MERGE_HEAD`.)

Git's `commit` knows, of course, about unborn and/or orphan branches.  If `HEAD` says `refs/heads/master`, but branch `master` does not exist ... well, then, `master` must be an unborn branch!  So this new commit has *no* parent ID.  It still has the same tree as always, but it is a new root commit.  It still gets its ID written into the branch file, which has the side effect of *creating the branch*.

Hence, it's *making the first commit on the new orphan branch* that actually creates the branch.

## Things you need to know about cherry-pick

Git's `cherry-pick` command is very simple in theory (practice gets a bit complicated sometimes).  Let's go back to our example graphs and illustrate a typical cherry-pick operation.  This time, in order to talk about some of the specific commits within the graph, I'll give them single-name letters:

```
...--o--o--A--B--C   <-- mong
      \
       o--o          <-- oose
```

Let's say we'd like to cherry-pick commit `B` from branch `mong` into branch `oose`.  That's easy, we just do:

```
$ git checkout oose; git cherry-pick mong~1
```

where `mong~1` designates commit `B`.  (This works because `mong` designates commit `C`, and `C`'s parent is `B`, and `mong~1` means "move back one parent commit along the main-line of first-parent links.  Likewise `mong~2` designates commit `A`, and `mong~3` designates the `o` just before `A`, and so on.  As long as we don't traverse a merge commit, which has multiple parents, everything is very simple here.)

But how does `git cherry-pick` actually work?  The answer is: it first runs `git diff`.  That is, it constructs a *patch*, of the sort shown by `git log -p` or `git show`.

#### Commits have complete trees

Remember (from our earlier discussion) that each commit has an attached tree object.  That tree holds the *entire source tree* as of that commit: a snapshot of everything that was in the index/staging-area when we made that commit.

This means that commit `B` has a whole complete work-tree associated with it.  But we want to cherry-pick the *changes* we made in `B`, not the *tree of* `B`.  That is, if we changed `README.txt`, we want to get the *change* we made: not the old version of `README.txt`, and not the new version, just the changes.

The way we find this is that we go from commit `B` back to its parent, which is commit `A`.  Commit `A` *also* has a whole complete work-tree.  We just run `git diff` on the two commits, which shows us what we changed in `README.txt`, along with any other changes we made.

Now that we have the diff / patch, we go back to where we are now—the tip commit of branch `oose`, and the files we have in our work-tree and in our index/staging-area that correspond to that commit.  (The `git cherry-pick` command will, by default, refuse to run at all if our index does not match our work-tree, so we know they are the same.)  Now Git simply applies (as with `git apply`) the patch we just obtained by diffing commits `A` and `B`.

Hence, whatever changes we made to go from `A` to `B`, we make those now, to our current commit / index / work-tree.  If all goes well, this gives us modified files, which Git automatically `git add`s to our index; and then Git runs `git commit` to make a new commit, using the log message from commit `B`.  If we ran `git cherry-pick -x`, Git adds the phrase "cherry-picked from ..." to our new commit's log message.

(**Hint: you usually want to use `-x`.**  It probably should be the default.  The main exception is when you are not going to keep the original commit you've just cherry-picked.  One can also argue that using `cherry-pick` is usually wrong—it's an indication that you did something wrong earlier, really, and now have to paper over it, and the papering-over may not hold up in the long run—but that's for another [long] posting entirely.)

#### Cherry-picking in an orphan branch

[VonC noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38285663/1256452) that in Git 2.9.1 and later, `git cherry-pick` works in an orphan branch; in an upcoming release it works for sequences as well as for individual commits.  But there is a reason this has been impossible for so long.

Remember, `cherry-pick` turns a *tree* into a *patch*, by diffing a commit against its parent (or, in the case of a merge commit, the parent you choose with the `-m` option).  It then applies that patch to the current commit.  But an orphan branch—a branch we have not yet made—has no commits, hence no current commit, and—at least in a philosophical sense—no index and no work-tree.  There is simply *nothing to patch*.

In fact, though, we can (and Git now does) just bypass this entirely.  If we *ever* had a current commit—if we had something checked out at some point—then we *still* have, right now, an index and a work-tree, left-over from the most recent "current commit", whenever we had it.

This is what `git checkout --orphan orphanbranch` does.  You check out some existing commit and hence populate the index and work-tree.  Then you `git checkout --orphan newbranch` and `git commit` and the new commit uses the current index to create—or actually, reuse—a tree.  That tree is the *same* tree as the commit you had checked out before you did `git checkout --orphan orphanbranch`.<sup>3</sup>

This is where the main part of my recipe for very-old-Git comes from as well:

```sh
$ commit=$(git rev-parse master~2)
$ git branch newbranch $( \
    git log --no-walk --pretty=format:%B $commit | \
    git commit-tree -F - "${commit}^{tree}" \
)
$ git checkout newbranch
```

First we find the desired commit and its tree: the tree associated with `master~2`.  (We don't actually need the variable `commit`, but writing it out like this lets us cut-and-paste a hash from `git log` output, without having to count how far back it is from the tip of `master` or whichever branch we are going to use here.)

Using `${commit}^{tree}` tells Git to find the actual tree associated with the commit (this is standard [`gitrevisions` syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)).  The `git commit-tree` command writes a new commit into the repository, using this tree we just supplied.  The parent(s) of the new commit come from the parent IDs we supply using `-p` options: we use none, so the new commit has no parents, i.e., is a root commit.

The log message for this new commit is whatever we supply on standard input.  To get this log message, we use `git log --no-walk --pretty=format:%B`, which just prints the full text of the message to standard output.

The `git commit-tree` command produces as its output the ID of the new commit:

```sh
$ ... | git commit-tree "master~2^{tree}"
80c40c288811ebc44e0c26a5b305e5b13e8f8985
```

(each run produces a different ID unless all are run in the same one-second period, since each one has a different set of time-stamps; the actual ID is not terribly important here).  We give this ID to `git branch` to make a new branch name that points to this new root commit, as its tip commit.

Once we have the new root commit on a new branch, we can `git checkout` the new branch, and we're ready to cherry-pick the remaining commits.

---

<sup>3</sup>In fact, you can combine these as usual:

```
git checkout --orphan orphanbranch master~2
```

which first checks out (puts into the index and work-tree) the contents of the commit identified by `master~2`, then sets up `HEAD` so that you are on the unborn branch `orphanbranch`.

---

#### Using `git cherry-pick` into an orphan branch is not as useful as we might like

I have here a newer version of Git built (it fails some of its own tests—dies during t3404-rebase-interactive.sh—but otherwise seems mostly OK):

```
$ alias git=$HOME/.../git
$ git --version
git version 2.9.2.370.g27834f4
```

Let's check out, with `--orphan`, `master~2` with new name `orphanbranch`:

```
$ git checkout --orphan orphanbranch master~2
Switched to a new branch 'orphanbranch'
$ git status
On branch orphanbranch

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   .gitignore
    new file:   a.py
    new file:   ast_ex.py
[snip]
```

Because this *is* a new branch, it looks to Git as though everything is new.  If I now try to `git cherry-pick` either `master~2` or `master~1`:

```
$ git cherry-pick master~2
error: Your local changes would be overwritten by cherry-pick.
hint: Commit your changes or stash them to proceed.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
$ git cherry-pick master~1
error: Your local changes would be overwritten by cherry-pick.
hint: Commit your changes or stash them to proceed.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

What I would have to do is clean everything out, in which case applying the change from `master~3` to `master~2` would be unlikely to work, or just do an initial `git commit` anyway, to make a new root commit based on the tree from `master~2`.

## Conclusion

If you have `git checkout --orphan`, just use that to check out the target commit `oldbranch~N` (or by hash ID, which you can cut-and-paste from `git log` output):

```
$ git checkout --orphan newbranch oldbranch~N
```

then make the new commit immediately, as [Nick Volynkin said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284471/1256452) (you can copy its message):

```
$ git commit -C oldbranch~N
```

so as to create the branch; and then use `git cherry-pick` with `oldbranch~N..oldbranch` to get the remaining commits:

```
$ git cherry-pick oldbranch~N..oldbranch
```

(And maybe use `-x`, depending on whether you plan to strip the commits from `oldbranch`.)  Remember, `oldbranch~N..oldbranch` excludes the commit `oldbranch~N` itself, but that's actually *good* because that's the one we made as the new root commit.

Comment: It is a bit of a short answer, with no footnotes (at the end, because there are intermediate footnotes), so I am a bit disappointed. Still +1 though.

Comment: The problem with those "parents" is that git users forget about "parent commits" and think more in term of "parent branch" (a notion which does not really exist). I always think about the git T-Rex answer when it comes to "parent branch": http://stackoverflow.com/a/3162929/6309

Comment: @VonC: Yes: "parent branch" *does* exist as a notion in other VCSes (e.g., Mercurial).  The reason it doesn't in Git is that it turns out to be as much of a problem as it is a solution.

Comment: It goes to show how radically different Linus' vision was about version control. Rather to be bogged down by paradigm of the past, where a "parent branch" made sense, he clearly define everything around content (commit). A branch becomes just a (transient) path in a graph, rather than a fixed first-class object.

Comment: Wow, this is a really comprehensive answer. Would you mind adding some `<!-- language: lang-bash -->`es?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: done; I marked a few anyway (where it made some items colorize correctly).  It's not great since it mis-marks the shell's output, so I usually don't bother :-)

Answer (score 6):

Do I understand you right, that you want the orphaned branch to already have a history of commits? If so, here's a solution.

First you need to pick a commit to start the new branch at. In my example this will be `HEAD~2`, `sha1=df931da`.

Say, we've got a simple repo. `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` shows the following:

```
* 4f14671 (HEAD, master) 4
* 1daf6ba 3
* df931da 2
* 410711d 1
```

Now, action!

```bash
# Move to the point where we want new branch to start.
➜  gitorphan git:(master) git checkout HEAD~2
```

Here and further the `➜  gitorphan git:(master)` part is zsh's prompt and not a part of the command.

```bash
# make an orphan branch
➜  gitorphan git:(df931da) git checkout --orphan orphanbranch
Switched to a new branch 'orphanbranch'

# first commit in it
➜  gitorphan git:(orphanbranch) ✗ git commit -m'first commit in orphan'
[orphanbranch (root-commit) f0d071a] first commit in orphan
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 1
 create mode 100644 2

# Check that this is realy an orphan branch
➜  gitorphan git:(orphanbranch) git checkout HEAD^
error: pathspec 'HEAD^' did not match any file(s) known to git.

# Now cherry-pick from previous branch a range of commits
➜  gitorphan git:(orphanbranch) git cherry-pick df931da..master
[orphanbranch 7387de1] 3
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 3
[orphanbranch 4d8cc9d] 4
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 4
```

Now the branch `orphanbranch` has a snapshot of working tree at df931da in a single commit and further commits just as they were in the master.

```bash
➜  gitorphan git:(orphanbranch) git log --oneline
4d8cc9d 4
7387de1 3
f0d071a first commit in orphan
```

Comment: +1, although git 2.9.x/2.10 will shorten a bit that process. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38285663/6309).

Comment: @VonC as always, you're on the frontier of git features ))

Comment: It was actually released 10 days ago with git 2.9.1, so it is old news now.

Answer (score 4):

[Nick Volynkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2790048/nick-volynkin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284471/6309) involves making at least one commit in the new orphan branch.
That is because a `git cherry-pick df931da..master` *without* that first commit would have lead to "`Can't cherry-pick into empty head`".

But not anymore, with git 2.9.X/2.10 (Q3 2016).

See [commit 0f974e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0f974e2124e5220674eee079988b87e23f5e2de1) (06 Jun 2016) by [Michael J Gruber (`mjg`)](https://github.com/mjg).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 25227f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25227f0beacf00d80420e313ffed48032352037f), 06 Jul 2016)</sup>

> ### `cherry-pick`: allow to pick to unborn branches
>
> "`git cherry-pick A`" worked on an unborn branch, but "`git cherry-pick A..B`" didn't.

That means the solution becomes:

```
# make an orphan branch
➜  gitorphan git:(df931da) git checkout --orphan orphanbranch
Switched to a new branch 'orphanbranch'

# Now cherry-pick from previous branch a range of commits
➜  gitorphan git:(orphanbranch) git cherry-pick df931da..master
```

No need for making a commit first, before cherry-picking.

Comment: However, cherry-picking may not produce the desired result given the form of the original question ... I should put in an answer here.

Comment: Actually, now that I've looked at it, cherry-pick does the desired thing (though 2.9.1 requires a first separate cherry-pick step and pre-2.9 requires a complete separate commit).

Comment: ... Or maybe not, quite.  Anyway, going ahead with writing up an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way to do it

```
git branch -m master old_master
git checkout --orphan master
```

-m = move branch to a new name
checkout - checkout the new master as orphan

Comment: How can you push it to the remote repository? The renamed master will not be existing there and you will get error messages,..

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have checkout a new branch and have made two commits as below. 13hh93 is the checksum for the checkout and 54hdsf is the checksum for the latest commit:

master => new_branch_1 (13hh93) => new_branch_2 => new_branch_3 (54hdsf)

Then proceed as follows. Step 1 goes to the start of the checkout. Step 2 creates an orphan branch from it. Step 3 applies the rest of the branch to your orphan branch.

1) git checkout 13hh93 
2) git checkout new_orphan_branch --orphan
3) git diff 13hh93 54hdsf | git apply

Answer (score 1):

After reading [torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38502873), I found that if you want to wipe away the history of a *checked-out* `BRANCH` and turn it into an orphan, without wasting time checking out a different branch or detached HEAD first, you can delete the branch using:

```sh
git update-ref -d refs/heads/BRANCH
```

This puts Git into "orphan branch" mode. Now you can stage and commit files as usual, which recreates the branch as a single commit without parents.

---

Note that you cannot delete a checked-out branch the normal way. Trying to run `git branch -d BRANCH` (or even `git branch --delete --force BRANCH`) while checked out prints a error message instead of following your instructions:

```
error: Cannot delete branch 'BRANCH' checked out at '/home/me/folder'
```

This is *usually* a safeguard against deleting a branch you don't want to lose, but prevents you from creating an orphan when you *do* want one.