# Git Push: What is the difference between HEAD:refs/heads/<branch> and <branch>?

Tags: git, push

What does command 1 do that command 2 doesn't?

```
1. git push <projectpath> HEAD:refs/heads/<branch>
2. git push <projectpath> <branch>
```

What is the meaning of "HEAD:refs/heads/"?

Comment: @axiac I have (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec). None of those address clearly the detached HEAD case, or highlight the exact nature of HEAD (current commit everywhere) Hence my answer to better illustrate that.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38496360/1256452) is correct (and upvoted), but I think another way of looking at this might make more sense.

Note that all of this is assuming that you're using the four-word form of `git push`, i.e., `git push remote refspec`.  The *`remote`* part here is usually just the name `origin`.  We'll define *`refspec`* better in a moment.

## What `git push` does

What `git push` needs to do (and therefore does) is to call up another Git instance on another machine,<sup>1</sup> then give that other Git a set of *references* (usually branch names, sometimes tag names) to update.  A *reference* is simply a name, like `master` or `v1.2`, that ideally *should* be fully-qualified (`refs/heads/master` or `refs/tags/v1.2`) so that we can be sure what *kind* of reference it is—branch, tag, or whatever.

In order for the other Git to update the references your Git hands over, your Git must *also* hand over some of those big ugly SHA-1 hashes: one per reference.  In other words, your Git is going to ask their Git to set *their* `refs/heads/master` to, say, `ed4f38babf3d81693a68d06cd0f5872093c009f6`.  (At this point—actually, just a bit before this point, really—your Git and their Git have a conversation about which objects yours want to send them, and which objects they already have, all done by these big ugly hash IDs.  Once the two Gits agree about what's going to be sent over, yours does the `counting objects` and `compressing objects` and then sends them the objects.  The "now, please set some names" part happens nearly last.)

#### Getting the name and hash parts

Note that there are two parts to your Git's request: (1) a fully-qualified reference, and (2) the big-ugly-hash.  (In fact, there's also a third part, the `--force` flag, but that part is easy and we can just ignore it.)  But where does *your* Git get these?

If you write:

```
git push origin somename
```

you've given *your* Git two pieces of information: the name `origin`, which your Git uses to look up the URL, and the name `somename`.  Your Git uses this to figure out the full name.  Is `somename` a tag?  If so, the *full* name is `refs/tags/somename`.  Is `somename` a branch?  If so, the *full* name is `refs/heads/somename`.  Either way works.  Of course, you can also write out the full name yourself—and if the name is both a branch *and* a tag, you may *want* to do that, rather than letting Git pick one for you.<sup>2</sup>

So, where does your Git get the big ugly hash?  The answer is: from that same name.  The name `somename`, whether it's a branch or a tag, just names some particular Git object.  If you want to see the hash yourself, you can do that any time:

```
git rev-parse somename
```

will show it to you.  This is, in fact, how I got `ed4f38babf3d81693a68d06cd0f5872093c009f6`: I went to a Git repository for Git and did `git rev-parse v2.1.1` and it printed out that hash, because `v2.1.1` is a valid tag in any complete copy of the Git repository since version 2.1.1 came out.

Note that when you *do* use this form—this `git push remote name` form—Git looks up the *`name`* argument in *your* repository for both purposes: to find out its full name, and to get its hash.  It doesn't matter where your `HEAD` is, only what that full name points to.

#### But Git does not have to use your branch's (or tag's) ID

The fourth argument to `git push` is called a *refspec*, and its syntax actually allows two parts separated by a colon:

```
 git push origin src:dst
```

In this case, the `dst` part supplies the *name*, but the `src` part supplies the hash.  Git runs the `src` part through `git rev-parse` and that produces the hash.  So you can:

```
git push origin mybranch:refs/tags/v42
```

to create tag `v42` in the other Git repository, using whatever commit hash your branch `mybranch` identifies.

#### Normally `HEAD` contains a branch name

In Git, `HEAD` *always* names the current commit.  *Usually* it does so by naming a branch, and letting the branch name the commit.  So, usually `HEAD` contains a branch name like `master`, and a branch name always gets you the *tip commit* of that branch (that's how Git *defines* "tip commit"; see the definition of branch in [the Git glossary](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html)).  But *always*,<sup>3</sup> `HEAD` can be turned into a commit:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD
2b9288cc90175557766ef33e350e0514470b6ad4
```

because `HEAD` is either a branch name (which is then the tip commit), or else you have a "detached HEAD", in which case Git stores the current commit ID directly in `HEAD`.

#### Pushing when HEAD is detached

Remember that in order to push, Git needs to get those two pieces of information: the hash, and a (full) name.  When `HEAD` *isn't* "detached", Git can get both from it: `HEAD` has a branch name—in the full name form, in fact—and the branch name has the hash.  But when you are in "detached HEAD" mode, `HEAD` only has a hash.  Git *can't* find a branch name in `HEAD`.  There might not *be* one: you might have checked out a commit by ID, or maybe you checked out by tag name, as in:

```
$ git checkout v2.1.1
```

which put you in this "detached HEAD" mode.

In this case, Git demands that you supply both the source hash `src`—you can still use the name `HEAD` to get it—*and* the `dst` destination name.  And, if you use `HEAD` as the source, Git really needs *you* to spell out the full destination, because Git can't tell, at this point, if it should be a branch (`refs/heads/dst`) or a tag (`refs/tags/dst`).<sup>4</sup>

## Other forms of `git push`

You can run `git push` with fewer arguments, e.g.:

```
git push origin
```

or even just:

```
git push
```

What happens here is that without a *`refspec`*, Git consults your `push.default` setting first.  Usually this is `simple` (the default since Git version 2.0).  In this case, Git simply uses `HEAD` to figure out what to push—which, of course, works only when `HEAD` is not detached.  That's just what we described above.

(Three of the other settings also use `HEAD`.  One of them—the one that was the default before Git version 2.0—does not, but that particular setting proved too error-prone, which is why the default changed.  You probably should not use it, at least not unless you are a Git master.)

(And, if you leave out the *`remote`*, Git again uses `HEAD` to figure out where to push to, defaulting, if needed, to `origin`.)

You can also push multiple refspecs:

```
git push origin branch1 branch2 tag1 HEAD:refs/tags/tag2
```

In this case, each refspec is handled in the usual way: get its fully qualified name if needed, so that your Git can give their Git a fully qualified name each time; and look up its hash ID if you didn't use the `src:dst` form (or if you *did* use the `src:dst` form, look up `src`'s ID instead).

You can use wildcards in refspecs:

```
git push origin 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```

(some shells will eat, mangle, [fold, spindle, or mutilate](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1542-734X.1992.1504_43.x/abstract) the `*`s so you may need to use quotes, as in this example; other shells won't—or at least usually won't—but it doesn't hurt to quote).  This will push *all* your branches, or at least try to.  This tends to be overly enthusiastic, pushing all your temporary work and experimentation branches, and is probably not what you want, but it's what Git did by default prior to version 2.0.

And, you can use an empty `src`:

```
git push origin :refs/heads/deleteme
```

which is a special-case syntax that means "have my Git ask their Git to *delete* that reference" (to delete a tag, spell out the tag).  As with a detached HEAD, the lack of a fully-qualified name on *your* side means you should fully-qualify the name for *their* side.  (See footnote 4 again.)

#### The force flag

If you add `--force` to your `git push` command, your Git passes this flag on to their Git.  Instead of a polite request—"please, sir, would you like to set your `refs/heads/master` to `ed4f38babf3d81693a68d06cd0f5872093c009f6`?"—your Git will send it as a rather insistent demand.  Their Git can still refuse either way, but their Git will, by default, do it even if it's not sensible.

Refspecs allow you to control this flag more tightly.  The force flag in an individual refspec is a leading plus sign `+`.  For instance, suppose you have new commits for both `master` and `develop` branches, and also a new set of *rebased* commits for `experiment`, which everyone else has agreed that you are allowed to force-push.

You could do this:

```
git push origin develop master; git push -f origin experiment
```

but you can combine it all into one big push:

```
git push origin develop +experiment master
```

The leading `+` on `experiment` makes *that* one a command ("update `experiment`!") while leaving the others as polite requests ("please, sir, if you like, update `develop` and `master`").

(This is all a bit esoteric for `push`, but is actually something you use regularly every day with `git fetch`, which uses refspecs with `+` flags to create and update your remote-tracking branches.)

---

<sup>1</sup>If the "other repo" is on your same machine and you're using a `file://` or local path based URL, this isn't quite true, but the principle is the same and the operations go the same way.

<sup>2</sup>Better yet, don't get yourself in this situation in the first place.  It's very confusing to have one name that is both a branch name *and* a tag name.  (There are similar confusing situations to avoid due to Git's habit of abbreviating: don't name branches with names that resemble remote names, for instance.  Git will handle them just fine, but *you* might not. :-) )

<sup>3</sup>Actually, there's one exception to this rule, which most people will never notice: when `HEAD` names an "unborn branch".  Mostly this occurs in a new repository, which has no commits at all.  Obviously, if there are no commits, there is no commit ID that `HEAD` could name.  It also occurs when you use `git checkout --orphan` to create a new orphan branch.

<sup>4</sup>If you use an unqualified name, their Git will look up the name to qualify it.  This means you may not know what kind of name you are trying to update or delete.  It's generally not a good idea, anyway.

Comment: "HEAD always names the current commit." so many people miss that. Like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/34519716/6309 for instance.

Comment: Regarding your last edit (footnote 3, unborn branch), git cherry-pick now fully work on an unborn branch! http://stackoverflow.com/a/38285663/6309 (git 2.9.1)

Comment: @VonC: Interesting.  Unborn branches in general present challenges since most of us (I include myself here) tend not to consider the "HEAD won't resolve" case.  If Git would parse `HEAD^{tree}` to the empty tree for this case, I think that would actually allow many scripts to Just Work.

Comment: @VonC: yes, that's the one. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Difference:

- `git push <projectpath> HEAD:refs/heads/<branch>`: the local branch commit can now differ from the remote branch commit, because "HEAD" can be detached (not linked to any branch)
- `git push <projectpath> <branch>`: the local branch commit will always be the same as the remote branch commit.

---

In detail:

A proper branch (meaning not a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)) is a commit stored in a refname directly referenced by `HEAD`.
That means [`HEAD` is a symbolic ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/967611/6309) to `refname` (which in turn contains the actual commit), or **directly to a commit ([detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309))**. See also "[HEAD: current commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/964927/6309)".

`HEAD:refs/heads/<branch>` is a **[refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec)**, with `<src>:<dst>`, where `<src>` is often the name of the branch you would want to push, but it can be any arbitrary "SHA-1 expression", such as `master~4` or `HEAD`, and `<dst>` tells which ref on the remote side is updated with this push.

If you have the following state:

```
   git checkout abranch

   --x--Y--W--Y--Z (HEAD abranch)
     |
  (origin/abranch)
```

A `git push origin aBranch` will push a branch HEAD (here Z) or origin, resulting in;

```
   --x--Y--W--Y--Z (FEAD, abranch, origin/abranch)
```

But if you checkout directly one of the new commits of abranch:

```
git checkout abranch~2

         (HEAD)
           |
   --x--Y--W--Y--Z (abranch)
     |
  (origin/abranch)
```

And then you push with the second syntax, you will update the remote tracking branch up to that `W` commit only:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/abranch

         (HEAD)
           |
   --x--Y--W--Y--Z (abranch)
           |
  (origin/abranch)
```

`git push origin aBranch` would still have pushed the full branch though, even if HEAD was not referecing `abranch`.

Comment: Niggle: For `push`, `<src>` is your (local) side and `<dst>` is their (remote) side.  The way you have them listed is for `fetch`.

Comment: @Razzle Pushing a detached HEAD will change the remote tracking branch commit, while your local branch could remain on its original commit. That would not happen when you push a branch (instead of a detached HEAD): the local branch commit and the remote branch commit remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

The first command explicitly pushes a branch with the given name. If you had, for example, a tag with an identical name to one of your branches, the second command would be ambiguous.