# old files already exist in my new created repo

Tags: git, gitlab

I got something really strange.

When I use `git push --set-upstream git@gitlab.example.com:namespace/nonexistent-project.git master` to generate a new repository, I found that there exist a folder in it which I upload 2 days ago.

Then I used `git ls-tree -r master --name-only` to list the all the files currently being tracked under the branch master. They are exactly what I have in my new repo.

But this trouble doesn't occur at all if I create a new project directly in the website then clone it to local and push the new modifications.

So what's the reason?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're reusing the same repository for a new project. If you want a new repository, you should leave any existing repositories and then run `git init PROJECT`, where `PROJECT` is the directory for the project you want to work on. You can then switch into that directory and work on your project. In this new project, you can run the `git push` command that you ran above, and things will work.

`git push --set-upstream REMOTE master` updates your existing repository's `master` branch to automatically fetch from and push to a new remote repository. However, it doesn't change the fact that your existing code from your old project is in your local repository because you're reusing the same *local* repository for your code.

Comment: I think I somehow understand your meaning. But even after I run `git init PROJECT` these files still in my local repo, by running `git ls-tree --full-tree -r --name-only HEAd`. So if I don't create new project in website in advance, but generate the new PROJECT by pushing it to the gitlab, I still mess it up with the old files. So how can I empty the repository or how can I use a different repository to push a new project with only new documents?

Comment: Once you've created the new project repository, you can do a `git pull OLD master` and then use `git log` to find the hash of the last commit of the old project. Then, you can follow [the steps in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352947/rebase-entire-development-branch-onto-new-master-branch) to rebase your new project onto an empty commit. Then, in the old project, run `git reset --hard HASH`, where `HASH` is the last commit of the old project.